# batch size in model.fit and model.predict

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

In `keras`, both `model.fit` and `model.predict` has a parameter of `batch_size`. My understanding is that batch size in model.fit is related to batch optimization, what's the physical meaning of `batch_size` in `model_predict`? Does it need to be equal to the one used by `model.fit`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No it doesn‘t. Imagine inside your model there is a function which increases the amount of memory significantly. Therefore, you might run into resource errors if you try to predict all your data in one go. This is often the case when you use gpu with limited gpu memory for predicting. So instead you choose to predict only small batches at the same time. The batch_size parameter in the predict function will not alter your results in any way. So you can choose any batch_size you want for prediction.

Comment: If memory availability is the main reason, would it be possible to automate it? Maybe get the memory available and make the batch_size adjust to it?

Comment: In the latest version of tensorflow (2.7.4), when predicting, not setting the batch_size will automatically max it. No need to find the biggest batch_size for prediction.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your model and whether the batch size when training must match the batch size when predicting. For example, if you're using a stateful LSTM then the batch size matters because the entire sequence of data is spread across multiple batches, i.e. it's one long sequence that transcends the batches. In that case the batch size used to predict should match the batch size when training because it's important they match in order to define the whole length of the sequence. In stateless LSTM, or regular feed-forward perceptron models the batch size doesn't need to match, and you actually don't need to specify it for `predict()`.

Just to add; this is different to `train_on_batch()` where you can supply a batch of input samples and get an equal number of prediction outputs. So, if you create a batch of 100 samples, you submit to train_on_batch() then you get 100 predictions, i.e. one for each sample. This can have performance benefits over issuing one at a time to `predict()`.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, batch size just increases the number of training data that is fed in at one go(batches). Increasing it may increase chances of your computer resources running out, assuming you are running it on your personal computer. If you are running it on the cloud with higher resources, you should be fine. You can toggle the number as you want, but don't put in a big number, I suggest going up slowly. Also, you may want to read this before you increase your batch size:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network